# STTwitter could not post image from iphone

Tags: ios, iphone, twitter, sttwitter

This is my code block that i use to post image to the twitter.

```
NSString *imagePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"info" ofType:@"png"];
    UIImage *image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:imagePath];
   NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image,.05);
    [_twitter postMediaUploadData:imageData fileName:@"splash_02" uploadProgressBlock:^(NSInteger bytesWritten, NSInteger totalBytesWritten, NSInteger totalBytesExpectedToWrite) {

    } successBlock:^(NSDictionary *imageDictionary, NSString *mediaID, NSString *size) {
        NSLog(@"xfdf=%@",imageDictionary);

    } errorBlock:^(NSError *error) {
          NSLog(@"xfdferror=%@",error);

    }];
```

I get response success but no image is posted

Answer (score 1):

As explained in Twitter's [documentation](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/multiple-media-extended-entities), this method does post the image and returns a `mediaID`, that can then be used in a tweet. Use this method when you want to post several images and use them all in a future tweet.

If you want to post an image along with a tweet, all in a row, see [STTwitter's methods](https://github.com/nst/STTwitter/blob/master/STTwitter/STTwitterAPI.h#L396-L427) for the `POST statuses/update_with_media` endpoint.